# Construct a continuous function with different limits in and outside of an interval

Tags: limits, continuity

I'm stuck with a question: Given an interval $[a, b] \subset\mathbb R$, construct a sequence of continuous functions $\phi_k (x)$ such that for every fixed $x \in\mathbb R$ we have

$$\text{lim}_{k \rightarrow \infty} \phi_k(x) = 
\begin{cases}1,\ \text{if } x \in [a, b],\\
0, \ \text{if } x \notin [a, b].
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to use a normal distribution with an infinite small variance of $\frac{1}{k}$ and mean $0$. But it seems that this distribution cannot satisfy the conditions simultaneously. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

$$\phi_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{for } x \notin [a-\frac 1n, b+\frac 1n]\\
\frac n2(x-a+\frac1n) &\text{for } x \in [a-\frac 1n, a+\frac 1n]\\
1 &\text{for } x \in [a+\frac 1n, b-\frac 1n]\\
\frac n2(\frac1n+b-x) &\text{for } x \in [b-\frac 1n, b+\frac 1n]\\
\end{cases}$$

which is a function that is $0$ outside the interval, $1$ inside the interval, and uses a little bit of the boundary to continuously transition from $0$ to $1$. (This continuous transition is sometimes called a linearization)